# how to append a string to an existing XML file in java

Tags: java, xml, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Append node to an existing xml-Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431238/append-node-to-an-existing-xml-java)

i am having this code

```
private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   File myfile;
   FileInputStream   myInputStream;
   InputStreamReader myInputStreamReader; 
   BufferedReader    myBufferedReader;

   String databasedir =
      "C:\\Users\\himu\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\database\\src\\database\\databases\\";
   try{
      myfile              = new File(databasedir+dbname.getText());
      myInputStream       = new FileInputStream(myfile);
      myInputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(myInputStream);
      myBufferedReader    = new BufferedReader(myInputStreamReader);

      String xmlval =
         "<database>"
         + "<db id ="  +dbname.getText() +">"
         + " <dbfileloc>" +myfile
         + "</dbfileloc>  "
         + "</db>"
         + "</database>";
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
   }
}
```

**I want to append the string xmlval after the previous entry of xmlval in the already created dbrepoloc.xml file  which is having this location C:\Users\himu\Documents\NetBeansProjects\database\src\database\dbrepoloc.xml i am not getting the exact code the place is mentioned above please help me

Comment: Google is your friend! You will find way to many links on XML Parsing on Google. Don't be lazy.

Comment: sir i want the code which i can put there to update the xml file i am not getting the exact code

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider one of the XML parsers to read and write a pre-existing XML document. Try [Stax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP2.html)

Also refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaXML/article.html

Comment: sir i want the code which i can put there to update the xml file  
i am not getting the exact code